# Devise and related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a User model which is managed by Devise.

I have an association with another model called Plans, as that a User has_many Plans.  And a Plan belongs_to an User.

I am trying to know the best way to allow a User to manage their Plans (create, edit, delete) and I fail to see which kind of controller I should create and how would my routes look.

Anyone could guide me through this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend, going through the Michael Hartl tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book or using scaffold generator to give you a good start

Devise, will handle all the login/authentication so you just need to think about what you want the user to do after they are logged in. If they are on the user homepage(show action) maybe you can put a link there to Add new plan. That means you need a way to handle that action. So you can create a plans controller....add the actions you want the user to take. For the routes, match whatever you want to each action you need. So you could add a plans resource or  the various actions (match 'new_plan', :to => "plans#new").